# Flutter and Firebase: Dynamic push notifications like Whatsapp

Tags: firebase, flutter

Most tutorials I've seen on the topic of notifications either broadcast notifications through the Firebase Console, or create in-app notifications that don't work if the app is in the background or is closed completely.

Is there a way to make notifications pop up dynamically using Flutter and Firebase even when the app is closed? Something like Whatsapp or Instagram notifications.

Reference image for what I mean by notifications like Whatsapp: https://www.techidence.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/WhatsApp-Nootifications.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to generate dynamic notifications directly from Flutter. Since to do this, the App has to be active. Usually you would send these kind of notifications from some kind of backend. Google Cloud Messaging exposes an API for this, which allows you to send POST requests to an Endpoint, and Google handles the sending of the actual notification.

Check this article under the point "1. Send Notification"

https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/firebase-cloud-messaging-important-rest-apis-be79260022b5

Comment: Is there any way to do this with Firebase Cloud Functions dynamically? As I said, most tutorials I've seen there do it from the Firebase console.

Comment: @raghavnautiyal I m sure there is, but I have no experience with it. Good luck